# Too many re-renders on pagination function in react

Tags: reactjs

I'm using useContext and useReducer and 
the data `jobInfo`is fetched every rendering by `useEffect`.
for Pagination, I needed to set local state 'pageInfo' and 
the data `jobInfo` took little time to be fetched so I had to
set `pageInfo`'s state after `jobInfo` is fetched.
anyway, because of `pageInfo`'s state renuwal, `jobInfo` is fetched again, and it cause `pageInfo`'s setState. (infinite loop)
How can I prevent infinite loop of re render?

```js
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import CheckboxFilter from '../components/filters/checkBoxFilter';
import DropdownFilter from '../components/filters/dropDownFilter';
import { JobInfoContext } from '../context/dataStore';
import { Link, useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import SearchFilter from '../components/filters/searchFilter';
import { Paginate } from '../utils/paginate';
import Pagination from '../utils/pagination';

const JobList = () => {
  const { jobInfo, loading } = useContext(JobInfoContext);
  console.log(jobInfo);
  const history = useHistory();
  const [pageInfo, setPageInfo] = useState({
    pageSize: 0,
    currentPage: 0,
  });

  // let pageSize;
  // let currentPage;
  let count;
  let infoForPaging;
  if (!loading && jobInfo) {
    setPageInfo({ pageSize: jobInfo.count, currentPage: jobInfo.page });
    count = jobInfo.count;
    infoForPaging = Paginate(jobInfo['data'],jobInfo.currentPage,jobInfo.pageSize
    );
  }

  let info;
  let showTable = (
    <TableRow key={uuid()}>
      <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
        loading...
      </TableCell>
    </TableRow>
  );
  if (!loading && jobInfo['data']) {
    info = jobInfo['data'].map((info) => info);
    showTable = infoForPaging.map((info) => (
      <TableRow key={uuid()}>
        <TableCell align="right">
          {info.due_at === null ? info.deadline : info.due_at}
        </TableCell>
        <TableCell align="right">
          {info.role === null ? '-' : info.role}
        </TableCell>
        <TableCell align="right">
          {ReactHtmlParser(info.industry === '' ? '-' : info.industry)}
        </TableCell>
      </TableRow>
    ));
  }

  const moveToNextPage = (page) => {
    // currentPage = page;
  };

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={moveToJobPost}>NEW POST</button>

      <div className={styles.container}>
        <div className={styles.filters}>
          <DropdownFilter value={webSiteName} filterName="웹사이트 선택" />
          <SearchFilter info={info} filterName="조회" />
        </div>
        <TableContainer component={Paper}>
          <Table className={classes.table} aria-label="simple table">
            <TableHead>
              <TableRow>
                <TableCell>Post date</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="right">Due date</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="right">Role</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="right">Industry</TableCell>
              </TableRow>
            </TableHead>
            <TableBody>{showTable}</TableBody>
          </Table>
        </TableContainer>

        <div className={styles.pagination}>
          {!loading && jobInfo && (
            <Pagination
              itemsCount={count}
              pageSize={jobInfo.pageSize}
              currentPage={jobInfo.currentPage}
              onPageChange={moveToNextPage}
            />
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default JobList;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, `PageInfo` state is just point over `jobInfo` values.

Consiedr points directly on `jobInfo`, and cut the middle man away.

Anyhow, your main issue is calling `setPageInfo` directly on component body and not through lifecycle (in this case `useEffect` triggered by `jobInfo` change), that way same `jobInfo` value won't create another re-render (due notice that if you follow that way and not the first suggestion, do not chain type object as trigger but id or like that)

```
useEffect(()=>{
if (!loading && jobInfo) {
    setPageInfo({ pageSize: jobInfo.count, currentPage: jobInfo.page });
    count = jobInfo.count;
    infoForPaging = 
    Paginate(jobInfo['data'],jobInfo.currentPage,jobInfo.pageSize
    );
  }
 }, [jobInfo.count,jobInfo.page])
```

Comment: oh my gosh..you are so right. I was stuck in a stupid idea. Thank you very much